# how to loop with while using bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

my problem is that i have to count the numbers of files whit a common part of the name (Stefano) in a folder (Name) and for every name i want to echo the name with the number of count's.
So names of the files in the folder will be like:

```
Stefano.A1
Stefano.B2
Stefano.H3
```

The problem i have is how to echo the files.Because it's giving me the error:

```
ls Stefano* | wc -l: syntax error in expression (error token is "Stefano* | wc -l")
```

here's the script

```
i=1

while [ $i -le $(ls Stefano* | wc -l) ]; do
      echo "Stefano*${i}"
      (i++)
done
```

Comment: i'm trying to make the expression  $i -le $(ls Stefano* | wc -l) go

Comment: check my answer, it should make it go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you want now... you want to make `$i -le $(ls Stefano* | wc -l)` work for your while loop, so do the following:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le $(cd $1 && ls Stefano* | wc -l) ]
do
    echo "Stefano*${i}"
    ((i++))
done
```

I added `cd` so that you can execute the script from whatever directory you are in, without actually moving you from your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

find prints out the names for you :)

```
find -name "*Stefano*"
```

Comment: `find` is an epic command, I posted an answer using find's regex but this is much cleaner!

Comment: I don't think OP wants to use find command... he said himself that he is trying to make `$i -le $(ls Stefano* | wc -l)` work for his script

Comment: You are right. But indeed the code just looked like he wants to print out the names ("The problem i have is how to echo the files."). so he could use find and if needed its -exec builtin.

Answer (score 0):

In BASH you can do:

```
i=1
for f in Stefano*; do
   echo "${f}${i}"
   ((i++))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something more simple using a for loop. Something like

```
for file in Stephano*; do (i++); done
```